# WinIOError Exception When Writing To File

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I'm using the following code to write to a file but my app keeps crashing with the following error which I believe is due to the file either being written to by another thread, or the file is open, even though I am catching the exception. I'm kinda new to C# so am I missing something obvious?

> Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
>      at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
>      at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32, Boolean)
>      at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String)

Code:

```
string[] lines = { "# Some Text here" };

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@Path + "\\testoutput.txt"))
        {
            try
            {
                 foreach (string line in lines)
                 {
                     file.WriteLine(line);
                 }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error writing to file!");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error writing to file!");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Exceptions from `new System.IO.StreamWriter(...)` are not catched. Just move the using into the try block.

Comment: I just copy and pasted this code into a console application, substituting `MessageBox.Show` with `Console.WriteLine` and it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks Klaus - that was it! I moved the using inside the try and now the exception is getting caught.